# Remove Elements From a List Which Are Multiplied for certain Parameter

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I'm working now with xAct in Mathematica obtaining huge list (around 50 000 terms) of contractions of a metric tensor with vector fields. I know that some elements of these list are multiplied for certain factor, let us call this for simplicity $f[x]$, and those elements should be deleted for consistency. So for example I will have

```
 List1={f[x]y,f[x]z,z^2,y,y^2,f[x]^2};
```

So a tried the simplest solution: divide the list by $f[x]$ and check the Denominator

```
 Redc=List1/(f[x]);
 Numc=Denominator[Redc];
```

Thus, if the Denominator is different from 1, I will keep that entry and delete the rest (from the original list). Unfortunately I could't find the solution. Perhaps It will be quite easy, but I'm not really expert on Mathematica. I appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: what about `DeleteCases`? As in `{f[x] y, f[x] z, z^2, y} // DeleteCases[f[x] _]`. This won't delete the `f[x]^2` instance, but it is easily adapted for those cases if that's what you needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually think that `Position[]` works best here, because it is more versatile than `Cases[]`, and will also delete powers. If this still misses some instances of the function, such as `Log[f[x]]` you may need to look at `FreeQ`, this assumes that this is not the case.

```
list={y fx[x], z fx[x], z^2, y, y^2, fx[x]^2};
Delete[list, Partition[Position[list, fx[x]][[All, 1]], 1]]
```

> `{z^2, y, y^2}`

Comment: Jesus!!..thank you so much @Feyre the solution works perfectly! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
Cases[ List1, _?(FreeQ[f])]
```

or

```
DeleteCases[ List1,_?(!FreeQ[f][#]&)]
```

> {z^2, y, y^2}